# How do I understand "time" in conditional probability and chain rule

Tags: probability, chain-rule

P(ABCD)=P(A|BCD)P(B|CD)P(C|D)P(D)

I really do not get this to be true, the reason is that the conditional statement say: Given this has happened already (If I am correct). So it tells something about the TIME when certain events occur in relation to other events.

Example: P(A|B) = probability for A to occur given B already has occurred or (B occure BEFORE A).

P(ABCD) = The same as the intersection of all the events happening, but tells nothing about certain events happening before others.

Any comments about this that may clarify, thank you for reading?

Comment: Conditioning has nothing to do with time.

Comment: It's more one trial, no time sequence, but there is information that $B$ has ocurrred. The question is, given that information, what is the probability that $A$ also occurred.

Comment: For example, if I roll a die, and tell you that the result is an even number, what is the (conditional) probability, based on that information, that the result is, $4$, say? There's no time sequence -- it's just one roll, but with (partial) information provided about the actual outcome.

Comment: So basically conditioning says in  P(A|B), A and B happen at once, and completely dismiss the time aspect of it, only what to be selected from a "set"?

Comment: I don't fully understand your last comment. But as I said, it's only one trial. For that trial either $A$ occurred or not, and either $B$ occurred or not. Each of those $4$ events has an absolute probability. The conditional probability, $P(A|B)$, is the probability that $A$ occurred, assuming knowledge that $B$ has occurred. That effectively cuts down the sample space.

Comment: Once again consider the roll of a die. Let $A $ be the event that the roll comes out to be one of $1,2,6$, and let $B$ be the event that the roll comes out even. Then $P(A) = 1/2$, and $P(B)=1/2$, but $P(A|B) = 2/3$. The original sample space is $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$, but if it's given that $B$ has occurred, the effective sample space, for any events conditoned on $B$, is $\{2,4,6\}$.

Comment: With the example in my previous comment, let $C$ be the event that the result is one of $1,2,3$. Then $P(A|BC)=1/3$. Thus, the new information that $B,C$ _both_ occurred changes your perception regarding the probability that $A$ occurred. Conditions are just partial information about the results of a single trial.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So for the equation
$$P(ABCD) = P(A|BCD)P(B|CD)P(C|D)P(D)$$
the RHS, reading from right-to-left, is

> The probability that $D$ occurred,
>
> times the probability that $C$ occurred, assuming knowledge (i.e., it's given that) $D\;$occurred,
>
> times the probability that $B$ occurred, assuming knowledge that $C,D\;$both occurred,
>
> times the probability that $A$ occurred, assuming knowledge that $B,C,D\;$all occurred.

But there is only one trial, no time sequence.

Each conditional probability represents a probability which takes into account the information provided (i.e., assuming the known occurrence of the events to the right of the vertical bar).

Comment: Thank you for the effort quasi

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right. For two events $A$ and $B$:
$$P(A\cap B)=P(A)\cdot P(B|A) \ \ (A, \ then \ B)$$
$$P(B\cap A)=P(B)\cdot P(A|B) \ \ (B, \ then \ A)$$
However, in the given formula, the information about the sequence of events is also indicated. Start interpreting from the end:
$$P(C|D) \ (D, \ then \ C)$$
$$P(B|C\cap D) \ (C\cap D, \ then \ B)=(D, \ then \ C, \ then \ B)$$
$$P(A|B\cap C\cap D) \ (B\cap C\cap D, \ then \ A)=\cdots=(D, \ then \ C, \ then \ B, \ then \ A).$$

Comment: Thanks, as a start, do I from this assume the "events" A, B, C ... etc are ordered in time?

Comment: Really not. Each condition is just additional knowledge about the _same_ trial. In that trial, each of the $4$ events $A,B,C,D$ either occurred or not.

Comment: I think it dawns, it is not about time, but selecting the right amount of information from a set. However when you mention (A then B), should it be A and B occur at the same time ?

Comment: I didn't say (A then B). That was farruhota's phrasing. It's only one trial, so if they both occur, then of course it's at the same time. The concept of $P(A|B)$ is the probability (for that _single_ trial) that $A$ occurred if you you have information that $B$ occurred, and no other information (other than the (absolute) probabilities for events in the original sample space).

Comment: I see, sorry. So this potential answer got assumptions about time that is not properly defined?

Comment: Right, I don't agree with how farruhota's answer was phrased.